# Mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I'm attempting to implement mixed effects logistic regression in python. As a point of comparison, I'm using the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package in R.

I've found that the `statsmodels` module has a `BinomialBayesMixedGLM` that should be able to fit such a model. However, I've encountered a number of issues:

1. I find the documentation for the `statsmodels` function to be not entirely helpful or clear, so I'm not completely sure how to use the function appropriately.
2. So far, my attempts have not produced results that replicate what I get when fitting the model with `glmer` in R.
3. I expect the `BinomialBayesMixedGLM` function does not calculate p-values since it is Bayesian, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the full posterior distributions for the parameters.

As a test case, I'm using the titanic dataset available [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/problem12.html).

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.genmod.bayes_mixed_glm as smgb

titanic = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'titanic.csv'))

r = {"Pclass": '0 + Pclass'}
mod = smgb.BinomialBayesMixedGLM.from_formula('Survived ~ Age', r, titanic)
fit = mod.fit_map()
fit.summary()

#           Type    Post. Mean  Post. SD       SD SD (LB) SD (UB)
# Intercept M           3.1623    0.3616            
# Age       M          -0.0380    0.0061            
# Pclass    V           0.0754    0.5669    1.078   0.347   3.351
```

However, aside from the slope for Age, this doesn't appear to match what I get in R with `glmer(Survived ~ Age + (1 | Pclass), data = titanic, family = "binomial")`:

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Pclass (Intercept) 0.8563   0.9254  
Number of obs: 887, groups:  Pclass, 3

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.961780   0.573402   1.677   0.0935 .  
Age         -0.038708   0.006243  -6.200 5.65e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So what error am I making when creating my model in python? And, once that's addressed, how can I extract either the posteriors or p-values? Lastly, are their any python implementations of mixed effect logistic regressions that are more akin to the implementation in R?

Comment: @petezurich -- For my own knowledge, why edit the title so that it no longer makes it clear that my question is specifically about how to fit this type of model in python? The new title seems must less descriptive for others searching to find an answer to a similar question.

Comment: This is what tags are for. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) *"it is completely unnecessary to include tags in your question titles."*

Comment: By the way: Your question seems off-topic and will likely get closed. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: @petezurich Thanks for the clarification and tips. After some more work, I've updated my question.

Comment: Cool! Makes sense. All the best and fingers crossed for your project.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution @YTD? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Blue482 Unfortunately, I pretty quickly gave up on this approach because I discovered that Julia has a MixedModels module that is virtually identical to lme4 in R and it was easy enough to use that instead. I'd still like to know if there's a good module for mixed models in python...

Comment: Maybe Bambi or Pymer4

Comment: Pymer4 looks like it might be exactly what I wanted. I'll have to check it out sometime.

Comment: I've tried to specify in `from_formula` logit link function, but I don't know how to use it. IMHO documentation to this method is poor and with no enough examples provided.

Comment: I'm a Bambi developer. Now you can work with mixed models much similar to what you would do in lme4, but using Bayesian statistics and in Python. Have a look at the repo https://github.com/bambinos/bambi, and feel free to open an issue if you need help.

Answer (score 7):

Just had to do something similar with `Python`, as suggested in the comments `Pymer4`
appeared to offer a suitable approach (especially if you are familiar with `R` anyway).
Using the example dataset 'titanic' referred to in the question:

```
from pymer4.models import Lmer

model = Lmer("Survived  ~ Age  + (1|Pclass)",
             data=titanic, family = 'binomial')

print(model.fit())
```

*OUT:*

```
Formula: Survived~Age+(1|Pclass)

Family: binomial     Inference: parametric

Number of observations: 887  Groups: {'Pclass': 3.0}

Log-likelihood: -525.812     AIC: 1057.624

Random effects:

               Name    Var    Std
Pclass  (Intercept)  0.856  0.925

No random effect correlations specified

Fixed effects:

             Estimate  2.5_ci  97.5_ci     SE     OR  OR_2.5_ci  OR_97.5_ci  \
(Intercept)     0.962  -0.162    2.086  0.573  2.616       0.85       8.050   
Age            -0.039  -0.051   -0.026  0.006  0.962       0.95       0.974   

              Prob  Prob_2.5_ci  Prob_97.5_ci  Z-stat  P-val  Sig  
(Intercept)  0.723        0.460         0.889   1.677  0.093    .  
Age          0.490        0.487         0.493  -6.200  0.000  ***
```

Just as an additional comment (sorry for diverting from the main question), I ran this on an `Ubuntu 20.04` machine with `Python 3.8.8`. Not sure if anyone else encountered this problem, but when running the model above with `Pymer4` the package threw an error (Same error when I tried to reproduce a similar model form the `Pymer4` documentation [here](http://eshinjolly.com/pymer4/auto_examples/example_02_categorical.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-example-02-categorical-py)):

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This can be fixed by updating the pymer4 version (see also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205026/pymer4-for-logistic-mixed-effects-regression-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-m/74848128#74848128)):

```
conda install -c ejolly -c conda-forge -c defaults pymer4=0.7.8
```

Comment: Using `design_matrix.any()` is likely wrong, the intended meaning of `if design_matrix:` is either checking if it is `None` (replace with `if design_matrix is not None:`) or checking that it is not an empty array (`if design_matrix.size > 0:`).

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy likely arises from different algorithms: [`glmer` uses approximate evaluation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lme4/html/glmer.html) of the integral involved (Gauss-Hermit quadrature), whereas [`BinomialBayesMixedGLM` uses variational Bayesian estimation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.bayes_mixed_glm.BinomialBayesMixedGLM.html#statsmodels.genmod.bayes_mixed_glm.BinomialBayesMixedGLM). The relevant Statsmodel page helpfully provides a link to [an article discussing the discrepancies between different evaluation methods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3866838/). The difference can be also seen when using `.fit_map()` (Laplace approximation) vs. `.fit_vb()` (variational Bayes) in Statsmodels - both different from the method used by `glmer`.

IMO the code given in the OP is correct, although I get somewhat different results with it:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

titanic = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")
r = {"Pclass": '0 + C(Pclass)'}
glmm = sm.BinomialBayesMixedGLM.from_formula('Survived~Age', r, data=titanic)
res = glmm.fit_vb()
print(res.summary())
```

resulting in

```
               Binomial Mixed GLM Results
========================================================
          Type Post. Mean Post. SD   SD  SD (LB) SD (UB)
--------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    M     0.8947   0.0747                      
Age          M    -0.0386   0.0023                      
Pclass       V     0.0565   0.3750 1.058   0.500   2.240
========================================================
Parameter types are mean structure (M) and variance
structure (V)
Variance parameters are modeled as log standard
deviations
```

The same results can be obtained without resorting to formula, which perhaps could give some more clarity (and could be hopefully helpful to those who, like me, encounter Statsmodels for the first time - like the OP I found the documentation not very transparent to non-statisticians):

```
titanic['Intercept'] = 1.
exog_vc = titanic.apply(lambda x: [x.Pclass==j for j in range(1, 4)], axis=1, result_type='expand').astype(int)
glmm = sm.BinomialBayesMixedGLM(titanic['Survived'], titanic[['Intercept', 'Age']], exog_vc, pd.Series([0, 0, 0]))
res1 = glmm.fit_vb()
print(res1.summary())
```

Here the last parameter (`ident`) allows relaxing the restrictions on variance of different components, e.g., all three classes could have different variance, if we take `ident = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])`.

Finally, more information can be gleaned from the result object, notably the means and the variances of the components: `res.params`, `res.vc_mean`, `res.vc_sd`, `res.vcp_mean`, `res.vcp_sd`. Note that `vcp_mean` is actually a logarithm of the variance, as it obeys [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) - hence it can be negative.

From documentation:

> There are three types of values in the posterior distribution: fixed effects parameters (fep), corresponding to the columns of exog, random effects realizations (vc), corresponding to the columns of exog_vc, and the standard deviations of the random effects realizations (vcp), corresponding to the unique integer labels in ident.
>
> All random effects are modeled as being independent Gaussian values (given the variance structure parameters). Every column of exog_vc has a distinct realized random effect that is used to form the linear predictors. The elements of ident determine the distinct variance structure parameters. Two random effect realizations that have the same value in ident have the same variance. When fitting with a formula, ident is constructed internally (each element of vc_formulas yields a distinct label in ident).
>
> The random effect standard deviation parameters (vcp) have log-normal prior distributions with mean 0 and standard deviation vcp_p.