# How can I solve the error: "The R package "lme4" is not installed when using the pymer4 library within python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, mixed-models

I am trying to follow the example detailed here: [Mixed effects logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403615/mixed-effects-logistic-regression), but I get a "PackageNotInstalledError: The R package "lme4" is not installed" at the line
`results = model.fit()`

The dataset can be downloaded here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv

My code is:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.genmod.bayes_mixed_glm as smgb
from pymer4.models import Lmer

titanic = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'titanic.csv'))

model = Lmer("Survived  ~ Age  + (1|Pclass)",
             data=titanic, family = 'binomial')

results = model.fit())

print (results)
```

The Lmer function works, it's just when I try to fit the model that I get the error. I had assumed the required packages would have been included within pymer4. Any ideas about how to install this package would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you install `pymer4` to begin with?

Comment: Did you read [Installation](http://eshinjolly.com/pymer4/installation.html), specifically the part where the authors explicitly recommend against installing with `pip`, and the section where they mention how to install the requisite R packages in tandem with the library itself (and what to do in the event the error you mention above is raised)?

Comment: Apologies that you feel my assistance was provided “*grudgingly*” by simply asking two questions requesting key details you failed to initially provide in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by reinstalling pymer4 using:

```
conda install -c ejolly -c defaults -c conda-forge pymer4
```